# Read JSON file vb.net

Tags: json

Good day,
I need to get some values from a JSON file, but I can not deserialize the file.
It is available here:http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/json

What I would like to get are the values of "mcversion" and "version" found in the "number" section, the remaining data not interest me.
I generated classes but do not work due to JSON format, this special is different.
I hope you can help me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To Read from a File you can use

```
Dim json As String = File.ReadAllText("JSON File Path")
Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
```